# Mysql system tables showing incorrect cardinality for columns

Tags: mysql, index-tuning, mysql-8.0, statistics, system-tables

I’m new to mysql. I have encountered a weird problem on our prod database. We have a table with primary key  `a` and an index on some other  `b` column. Below’s the query:

```
select b from my_table where a in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12....n) ;
```

Ideally for such cases my query should use PRIMARY KEY index of column `a`. Also, I have verified that by default my column `a` should have all unique values which it already has.

And my column `b` has several of duplicate values.

But, when I checked execution plan, the query is using index on column `b` `(b-idx)` rather than PRIMARY KEY index.

I ran analyze on this table, but even after there are no changes into execution plan. I can’t run optimize since it’s on prod.

Then, I checked for `show index from  my_table ;`

And, there I found quite weird thing, Cardinality value for column a was lower than column `b` . I guess by default optimizer picks up higher cardinality column, so it’s picking column `b-idx`

Please guide me what to do in such cases. Is this any bug in mysql or expected behaviour ?

I couldn’t find how to update stats for specific index on prod table.  I want our query to use right index by default

Comment: *Ideally for such cases my query should use PRIMARY KEY index of column a.* No. Only when the values list is short (approximately - not more than 10 values). Ideal case is to create an index by `(a, b)`.

Comment: *And, there I found quite weird thing, Cardinality value for column a was lower than column b .* Index statistic is approximate. Run ANALYZE TABLE.

Comment: @Akina - i executed ANALYZE TABLE already. However, it didn't update cardinality value for indexes. Is there any way to just analyze index itself

Comment: one more thing I couldn't understand why my query is considering orderno index even